# FQL get posts from stream on updated_time, need to find equivalen Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

FQL will be obsolete in API 2.1. If any user creates a new APP, then the user is forced to use API 2.1 features, as a result, I need to remove all FQL and replaced with Graph API to server the new users who create a new app.

Here is the quesion, We use FQL to fetch all posts on wall based on updated_time, and then we can fetch all newly comments reply to these posts on the page. This is the way we can fetch all the newer comments since last update. the FQL syntax look like this.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/fql?q=SELECT post_id, comment_info FROM stream WHERE source_id = ' owner ' and updated_time >=' since

Does any one know the equivalent feature in Graph API. I have been looking documents but unable to find it. Please help in coming out an alternate approach to achieve the same functionality, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's unfortunately no equivalent in the Graph API. The `since` request parameter is relative to the `created_time` AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Then how do we get the delta comments after 'since'. For example, if someone comments on a week old post, the only change on the main post is the updated_time set to the created_time of the comment. The only way I know is get to the main post in order to fetch the delta comments. Is there any other way? Thanks again.